# codeiginiter session did not work

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

in codeiginiter session class and pagination class  did not work together  ...

```
function soxml()
    {
    $this->load->library('session');
```

`$this->load->library('pagination');

$this->session->set_userdata('some_name', 'some_value');// did not  work 

$config['base_url'] = 'my_url';

$config['total_rows'] = 200;

$config['per_page'] = 20;

$this->pagination->initialize($config);

echo $this->pagination->create_links();
}

function snxml($id)
{
  echo $this->session->userdata('some_name'); // return blank ....did save any value  
}`

Answer (score 1):

You've just chosen the wrong key to look for:

```
echo $this->session->userdata('some_name');
```

You need to get `some_name` to get it's value.

Answer (score 0):

set_userdata function can also receive an array like

```
$newdata = array(
                   'username'  => 'johndoe',
                   'email'     => 'johndoe@some-site.com',
                   'logged_in' => TRUE
               );
```

so you could try pass it an array~

```
$array = array(
  'some_name' => 'some_value'
);
$this->session->set_userdata($array);
```

but, the best advise is to add the sentence `$this->load->library('session');` to __construct  ~good luck~

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options:

1) Load again the library on 2nd function like:

```
function snxml($id)
{
    $this->load->library('session');
    echo $this->session->userdata('some_name'); 
}
```

2) Remove this `$this->load->library('session');` from 1st function and load library in construct like:

```
public function __construct(){
    $this->load->library('session');
}
```